# mysql query with two table joins

Tags: mysql

Folks

I have 2 tables countrycodes,cctonumbers as described below.

I have the query that i tried but not getting the desired output.

**My Output**

```
 country          destination                     country_code   destination_code

Afghanistan  Afghanistan Mobile Etisalat              93        78
Afghanistan  Afghanistan Mobile Etisalat              93        72
Afghanistan  Afghanistan Mobile Roshan                93        79
Afghanistan  Afghanistan                              93        93
```

**Desired output**

```
country          destination                     country_code   destination_code

Afghanistan  Afghanistan Mobile Etisalat             93           78

Afghanistan  Afghanistan Mobile Etisalat             93           72    

Afghanistan  Afghanistan Mobile Roshan               93           79
```

The tables used are as below

**countrycodes table**

```
id       parentid   countryname 
1031     0          afghanistan 
1035     1031       Afghanistan Mobile Etisalat
1036     1031       Afghanistan Mobile Roshan
```

**cctonumbers table**

```
id       countrycode_id     parentid         number 
15731    1031               0                93
15197    1035               15731            78
15198    1035               15731            72
15199    1036               15731            79
```

The query that i m using is as below but not getting desired result.

```
select * 
   from 
      cctonumbers 
         LEFT JOIN countrycodes as CC 
            ON cctonumbers.countrycode_id = CC.id 
   WHERE 
      (     CC.parentid=0 
        AND number like '93%'
        and cctonumbers.id in 
                ( select cctonumbers.parentid 
                     from cctonumbers 
                        LEFT JOIN countrycodes as CC 
                           ON cctonumbers.countrycode_id = CC.id 
                        WHERE number like '7%'
                          AND CC.parentid!=0 )
                ) 
          or (     CC.parentid != 0 
               AND number like '7%' 
               AND CC.parentid in 
                       ( select CC.id 
                            from cctonumbers 
                               LEFT JOIN countrycodes as CC 
                                  ON cctonumbers.countrycode_id=CC.id 
                            WHERE CC.parentid=0 
                              AND number like '93%' )
             ) 
   ORDER BY 
      cctonumbers.number Asc
```

Comment: Could you make it clear what you are trying to get as a result?

Comment: I think you are trying to order them hyerarchically?

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to be looking for is all destinations associated with a specific country code.  Since you not actually showing any return results for your cctonumbers.id = 15731, I think you were spinning to get your results.  Let's reverse the tree instead of walking down it.

Start with only those CCToNumbers records that have a parent ID as it appears you are only 1-level deep.  Once you have those child-level entries, join back to CCToNumbers on its parent... then go to the country codes tables for both respectively.

```
SELECT
      CtoN.ID,
      PCountry.CountryName,
      DCountry.CountryName as Destination,
      CtoNParent.Number as Country_Code,
      CtoN.Number as Destination_Code
   from 
      cctonumbers CtoN
         JOIN cctonumbers as CtoNParent
             ON CtoN.parentid = CtoNParent.ID
            AND CtoNParent.number like '93%'
            JOIN countrycodes as PCountry
               ON CtoNParent.CountryCode_Id = PCountry.ID
         JOIN countrycodes as DCountry
            ON CtoN.CountryCode_Id = DCountry.ID
   where
      CtoN.number like '7%'
```